# Flutter sound alarm in background and cancel on notification tapped

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Flutter sound alarm in the background and cancel when the notification is clicked on.

I am trying to create a basic alarm app for testing/learning flutter. The high-level design for my app looks like this:

Creating alarm:

(a). User creates alarm
(b). I use android_alarm_manager to schedule alarm
(c). On alarm callback, I use FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm()
(d). Use `flutter_local_notification` to show the notification when the alarm rings, so that the user can cancel the alarm.

When the user taps on notification:

- I get a callback for `flutter_local_notification`, which opens the app.
- I do `FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop()` in that, but it doesn't stop the alarm.

It doesn't work right now because `FlutterRingtonePlayer` is constructed again when the app starts again from the notification.

Possible solutions I can think of is:

1. Somehow persist `FlutterRingtonePlayer` in the phone's shared memory so that I can reuse it when canceling the alarm. Maybe somehow serialize it?
2. Figure out a way to stop all the sounding things for the phone at that moment.

Are there more? Any better way to do this?

```dart
Here is my code:

--------------- Scheduling alarm -----------------------------------

void scheduleAlarm(Alarm alarm) {
  alarm.alarmTime =
      getUpdatedAlarmDateTime(TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(alarm.alarmTime));

  AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      alarm.alarmTime.difference(DateTime.now()), alarm.alarmId, soundAlarm,
      wakeup: true, alarmClock: true, rescheduleOnReboot: true);
}

void soundAlarm(int alarmId) async {
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker');
  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
      androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
  await globalPlugin.show(10, 'title', 'body', platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: '$alarmId');

  FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm(
    looping: true,
    volume: 0.9,
  );
}

--------- End Scheduling alarm ----------------------------------

-------- Setting up notifications callback ---------------------

Future initializeNotificationPlugin() async {
  var initializationSettingsAndroid =
      new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
      initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
  await globalPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
}

Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
  await FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop();
}

---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

As indicated before, ***no need*** to use `FlutterRingtonePlayer`, and here is a more detailed answer, in `AndroidNotificationDetails`, there's this property `additionalFlags` and by setting this property to 4, the notification will keep ringing until user taps it. Code sample how to do, extracted from [this example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/example) is:

```
 .
 .
 .
 //This flag
 const int insistentFlag = 4;

final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'ticker',

        //Exactly here
        additionalFlags: Int32List.fromList(<int>[insistentFlag]));
 .
 .
 .
```

Answer (score 1):

in flutter local notification, you can set the alarm to be insisted by setting extra flag 4, and thus keep the alarm repeat until user tap on it

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, I couldn't found any answer on the web but the solution is pretty easy, you just need to stop the sound the same way you play it, which means to use `android_alarm_manager` inside `onSelectNotification` with 0 second duration to call other function to stop the sound.
Here is my code using `android_alarm_manager` and `audio_player`:

```
stopTheSound() async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration(seconds: 0), 4, stopSound,
        exact: true, wakeup: true, alarmClock: true, allowWhileIdle: true);
  }
  
  static stopSound() async {
    if (MyApp.isPlaying) {
      var res = await audioPlugin.stop();
      if (res == 1) {
        MyApp.isPlaying = false;
      }
    }
  }
```